# Power mux design

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, multiplexer

In my board I have two power sources: **5V and 12V**

I would like to either power a **5v sensor** or **12v sensor** which will be attached to a connector on my PCB. For that I need to provide either **12v(300mA)** or **5v(300mA)** to this connector by a command coming from the MCU. So I am wondering if you could help me with a design of a mux or a part **number mux** that could achieve this functionality. I found the **TPS2120, TPS2121 and TPS2124** of TI but they are **not available** in the market.

Comment: Did you consider using a relay with SPDT contacts? Of course, there are solutions with semiconductor but relay is easy to find, cheap and easy to implement.

Comment: sure, but in the meantime relays aks for a large space on the pcb

Comment: Semiconductor power muxes are best where space is a problem. The TPS21xx range of muxes are your best bet, but due to a generalized world-wide shortage of many other type semiconductors, the ones you may find are perfect may not be stocked anywhere till probably next year.

Comment: In the mean-time you can simplify instead if you can't find the part in stock, by using transistors and schottky diodes in common-cathode configuration, to select one voltage or the other, and switch on-off at least one rail (say 12V) for control ... this will dissipate more power in the diodes than a TPS2120 or TPS2121, but at least you'll be able to get it done with available components ...

Comment: Just add an extra pin on the connector so that both supplies are available.

Comment: but the spec tells me to provide only one output to power the sensor

Comment: then you may consider the following to see if they do a similar job for your application : ICL7673 good luck.